# Computing the Adjoint of an Operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian, adjoint-operators, computer-algebra-systems

Can a computer take in a linear operator and set of boundary conditions, and compute the adjoint operator/conditions?

I can find calculators/Mathematica code/etc. to compute the adjoint of a matrix, but not for the adjoint of an operator.

If so, how can I do this?  If not, is there another way to check hand computations of operator adjoints?