# Green's Function Computation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem, greens-function

I want to calculate Green's Function to solve $\triangle u = f(x,\ y)$, using Laplace Transforms.  My plan was to tailor boundary conditions to the problem which simplify the computation.

Because the Laplacian is self-adjoint, my associated Green's Function equation can immediately be written as $G_{xx} + G_{yy} = \delta(x - x_G,\ y - y_G)$.

Laplace Transforming $y$ to $s$ and $G$ to $\hat G$, I get $\hat G_{xx} + s^2 \hat G - sG(x,\ 0) - G_y(x,\ 0) = e^{-y_G s} \delta(x - x_G)$.  Thus to simplify things, I'll go back and include $u(x,\ 0) = 0,\ u_y(x,\ 0) = 0$ in the problem statement, so that the terms with $G(x,\ 0)$ and $G_y(x,\ 0)$ drop out.  Actually, I'm not $100$% sure if this is correct.  I'm waiting on the results of some [other](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4394859/finding-boundary-conditions-that-make-this-greens-function-nice) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4394717/computing-the-adjoint-of-an-operator) to understand/play around with this more.  Regardless, let's assume I prescribe some boundary conditions on $u$ such that $G(x,\ 0)$ and $G_y(x,\ 0)$ drop out.  Now I have the ODE $\hat G_{xx} + s^2 \hat G = e^{-y_G s} \delta(x - x_G)$.

Laplace Transforming $x$ to $r$ and $\hat G$ to $\hat{\hat G}$, I get $r^2 \hat{\hat G} - r \hat G(0,\ s) - \hat G_x(0,\ s) + s^2 \hat{\hat G} = e^{-y_G s}e^{-x_G r}$.  Again to simplify things, I'll go back and include $u(0,\ y) = 0,\ u_x(0,\ y) = 0$ in the problem statement.  Now I have $\hat{\hat G} = e^{-y_G s}e^{-x_G r}\frac{1}{r^2 + s^2}$.

Inverting from $r$ back to $x$, by applying the shifting theorem, I think I should get $\hat G = e^{-y_G s}\frac{\sin(s(x - x_G))}{s}H[x - x_G]$, where $H[\ ]$ is the Heaviside step function.

Inverting from $s$ back to $y$, the first factor is another shift, and the last factor is constant with respect to $s$, so the challenge is to find the inverse transform of $\frac{\sin(s(x - x_G))}{s}$.  This does not seem easy to find directly (using tables or software; I don't know how to do it with Complex Analysis), so I break the sine function into exponentials and use $\frac{e^{\_\_\_s}}{s} \iff H[y + \_\_\_]$ for each exponential.  After some algebra, I arrive at $$G = \frac{H[y - y_G - xi + x_G i]H[x - x_G]H[y - y_G]i - H[y - y_G + xi - x_G i]H[x - x_G]H[y - y_G]i}{2}$$

The Boundary Value Problem has been refined into $\triangle u = f(x,\ y),\ u(x,\ 0) = 0,\ u_y(x,\ 0) = 0,\ u(0,\ y) = 0,\ u_x(0,\ y) = 0$.  Is this the correct Green's Function for this BVP?  If so, then how can I proceed to clean it up into a real, and more useful, expression and use it to solve the BVP for some particular forcing function?  If not, then what went wrong?  If the $i$'s cannot be eliminated, is this an indication that I should use the Fourier Transform instead of the Laplace Transform for one or both steps?  Would a better choice of boundary conditions produce a more palatable Green's Function?

Comment: Do you insist on using Laplace transform? If so I don't think it is valid to set both $u$ and $\partial_y u$ to vanish along $y=0$, because this would over-determine the solution. If you want to find $G$ by any method: directly integrate the equation for $G$ (over a disc) after casting the Laplacian in spherical polar co-ords, then appeal to the divergence theorem

Comment: @Sal I would like to use a Laplace or Fourier Transform if it is possible.  I have seen the method you alluded to but I am much more comfortable handling delta functions via transform, so I think this will stick better if I figure out that approach.  I am open to an alternative boundary condition; I just want to keep them as simple as I can.

Comment: In that case Fourier transform is simpler. About boundary conditions: have a look at the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function#Green's_functions_for_the_Laplacian). In the expression $\varphi=\int_V \dots+\int_S\dots$, it is convenient to choose $G$ such that one of the terms in the $\int_S$ vanishes. This depends on the type of boundary conditions. The `simplest' would be all Dirichlet or all Neumann.